# Send Welcome Email to user after Signup in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, email

I Have a app that user Signed up after complete form with ajax,My Code in Controller is here:

```
 public function store(request $request){
   $this->validate(request(),[
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ]);
    $user=Auth::user();
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->password=$request->password;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    auth()->login($user);
    $user->save();
    return $request->all();
}
```

Now I Want send Welcome email to user after register.How I Can do it?what Setting I need to this work?

Comment: Read first, then come with at least a try. [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail)

Comment: Start by overriding the `function registered(Request $request, $user)` method in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php` then use the mail docs linked above

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have two options: create an event and listener, or use an Eloquent observer. I would use the latter.

Essentially you create an observer on the User model which you can attach custom actions to when a model is persisted - here you could send off an email as you also have access to the saved model data (including user's name and email address).

For reference, check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers

Hope this helps.